# How can I validate the configuration of windsor castle

Tags: validation, configuration, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor, ioc-container

I want to assert that my registrations are valid, i.e no dependency is missing and there are no circular dependencies.
I'd like to do that in my application (and not in a unit-test) so I'd be able to fail-fast if the configuration is invalid.
I also want to accomplish that without resolving (and instantiating) all the components - only by scanning the dependency graph.
Any idea on how I can do that?

The motivation is the trial-and-error nature of configuring complex applications. I'd prefer to get a fail-fast behavior in case of a badly configured container.

BTW - my inspiration came from AutoMapper's AssertConfigurationIsValid() method.

Comment: when I come across a term I don't know, I ask my friend Google.  I did that with "windsor castle", and all I got was the English castle residence of their queen.  I bet that is not what your talking about, so please enlighten me.

Comment: Jay, perhaps if you checked other questions with the same tags as this one that would provide the answer for you...

Comment: Jay - Windsor is an inversion of control container from the Castle project. Check it out at http://www.castleproject.org/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't be 100% sure as Windsor is a dynamic organism and not everything can be statically analyzed. All handlers may be in `WaitingDependency` state yet your app may be 100% working since at resolution time the dependencies will be provided by `DynamicParameters`, `ISubDependencyResolver`s or `ILazyComponentLoader`s.

There were plans to include this functionality you've mentioned into Windsor, but given above constraints, it would rarely provide any value.

I would suggest having good, solid verifiable conventions that decide what goes into the container and what not, and good unit tests that test the container by resolving the components.

If you don't mind getting false negatives you can do the following:

```
var allHandlers = container.Kernel.GetAssignableHandlers(typeof(object));
```

and then iterate over them and check if they all are `Valid`, but I'd rather have a dedicated test for that. [Take a look at this post for example](http://weblogs.asp.net/bsimser/archive/2008/06/27/testing-castle-windsor-mappings-part-deux.aspx).

Configuring the application does not have to be trial and error, nor should it be. It's a matter of good conventions, and sticking to them. I have two posts about it you may find useful:

- [Build your conventions](http://kozmic.pl/archive/2010/04/08/build-your-conventions.aspx)
- [Validate your conventions](http://kozmic.pl/archive/2010/03/22/validate-your-conventions.aspx)

Comment: The motivation of course is the trial-and-error nature of configuring complex applications. I'd prefer to get a fail-fast behavior in case of a badly configured container.  
Perhaps you could supply a tristate verification method that will return valid, invalid or inconclusive result?  
I rarely use the dynamic features of Windsor, and I believe most of the times my wrong configuration can be caught early.

Comment: "Configuring the application does not have to be trial and error, nor should it be." Even if it's not, the fact that Windsor seems to just *give back `null`* instead of actually throwing the error when there's a problem constructing an object makes it *very* difficult to figure out what's going on. This happens to me, for example, when a database connection cannot be established; my application explodes much later with a `NullReferenceException` instead of a useful message about not being able to connect.